# JPA and Hibernate, atomic CreateOrUpdate on a relationship

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using SpringBoot with JPA and Hibernate.

I have two entities: Course and Subscriber.

For a Course I could have many Subscribers, so, into Course entity I have a OneToMany relationship with Subscriber.

Now, given a Course, I need to have a sort of 'CreateOrUpdate' function to add a Subscriber.
Basically, the requirement is this: if I will receive a new subscriber for a course, I need to create a new Subscriber if not exists or update the existing subscriber (updating only some fields).

Using JPA and Hibernate, is there the INSERT_or_UPDATE  on a relationship? I would like to avoid to use two queries just to check if the subscriber already exist + one more query to update or create it.

Is it possible?

Comment: If there is an ID associated with this subscriber, the method `saveOrUpdate` does exactly what you are looking for, no?